# Pycharm,Selenium Process finished with exit code zero

Tags: python, selenium

When i'am trying to run my code though Pycharm it doesnt execute anything. Normally it should run code and Chrome should start.

1) Tried to run from Terminal still the same.

```
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import unittest

class SearchText(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.driver.get('http://book.theautomatedtester.co.uk/')
        self.driver.maximize_window()
        time.sleep(2)
        self.driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[0])

    def test_search_by_text(self):
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/ul/li[1]/a').click()
        self.driver.find_element_by_id('radiobutton').click()
        self.driver.find_element_by_id('selecttype').send_keys('Selenium Code',Keys.ENTER)
        self.driver.find_element_by_name('selected(1234)').click()
        self.driver.find_element_by_id('storeinput').send_keys('Salamlar')
        self.driver.find_element_by_id('secondajaxbutton').click()
        self.driver.find_element_by_id('multiplewindow').click()
        self.driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[1])
        self.driver.find_element_by_id('closepopup').click()
        self.driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[0])
        self.driver.find_element_by_id('loadajax').click()
        self.driver.find_element_by_id('ajaxdiv')
        assert driver.page_source.find('The following text has been loaded from another page on this site. It has been loaded in')
        aka = driver.find_element_by_id('verifybutton')
        if aka.is_enabled():
            aka.click()
        else: print('Not Existing')

    def tearDown(self):
        # close the browser window
        self.driver.quit()
```

Expected Result: Code will trigger Browser and will run test

Comment: is that all of your code? do you have a `if __name__ == "__main__":` line any where? Because nothing is being told to run in the above code

Comment: @Matt Camp . Thanks exactly , i was missing it...

Comment: @PixelEinstein I didnt find my answer. Thats why i asked this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not actually execute anything.
If you want to execute the unittest you have to call `unittest.main()`. And since this should only be done when executing the file itself, you should add this at the bottom of your file.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```